# How do I get Choice Values from a Document library's Choice column in code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am fairly new to SharePoint development and as you may all know that it is very basic for one to know how to access fields in a choice column...

My problem: 
I want to access the values of the Check Boxes from a Choice Column.

For Example: 
I have a document library called Libe, this document library has a custom column with type Choice and has 4 checkboxes with the values:

1. Category 1
2. Category 2
3. Category 3
4. Category 4

How do I get the values like literally the text values of what is in the Check Box List: "Category 1", "Category 2" ... "Category 4".

Any ideas?

I can access the column fine and get the selected values, I just do not know how to get the values the user can choose from.

### Answer

```
 SPFieldMultiChoice Fld = (SPFieldMultiChoice)list.Fields["Column"];
                                List<string> fieldList = new List<string>();
                                foreach (string str in Fld.Choices)
                                {
                                    fieldList.Add(str);


     }
```

Above is the answer, I can't answer my own question until I have a 100 rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servername/"))
        {              
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];
                    string values = list["yourColumn"] as string;
                    string[] choices = null;
                     if (values != null)
                       {
                              choices = values.Split(new string[] { ";#" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                       }
                } 
        }
```

You can try this code for getting choice field value from document library.

Comment: Thank you, yes that is almost exactly as I did last week and it worked.